# facing error while deleting record from sqlite database

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, android-intent

Hi i am facing trouble right now facing bug while deleting a record from sqlite database. just make Sqlite class i am working on three file. One is placeorder file where i call the cartAdpter this displays all records in custom list when i click on the holder.delete button i made a obj of sqlite db and call delete method but it generate exaption .

**Place Order File**

```
public class PlaceOrder extends Activity {

    String [] pIds; 
    String [] pNames; 
    String [] pPrizes; 
    ListView lv;
    ImageView bck;
    String [] listImages;
    String food_id;
    String userdata[];
    Intent i;
    TextView totalprze;
    float tprize;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        bck=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder_bg_btn);
        totalprze =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_order_price);

        i=new Intent(this,Menu.class);

        bck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

                    //bundle.putStringArray("images", ListImages);
                    bundle.putString("food_id", food_id);
                    bundle.putStringArray("images", listImages);
                    bundle.putStringArray("userData",userdata);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        if(this.getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {

         Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();

         pIds=b.getStringArray("pId");
         pNames=b.getStringArray("PName");
         pPrizes=b.getStringArray("pPrize");
         userdata=b.getStringArray("userData");
         tprize=b.getFloat("totalprize");


         food_id=b.getString("food_id");
         listImages=b.getStringArray("images");
         String prz=Float.toString(tprize);
         totalprze.setText("$"+prz);
         lv.setAdapter(new cartAdapter(PlaceOrder.this, pIds, pNames, pPrizes));

       }
    }

}
```

**cartAdapter file**

```
public class cartAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{

     String [] pIdz;
     String [] pNamz;
     String [] pPrizs;
    // List<String> imges;
     Context context;
     private ShopingCartHelper obj;

     private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
     JSONArray jCat = null;
     int count=0;
     ProgressDialog pDialog;


     public cartAdapter(PlaceOrder ctx,
             String[] pIds,String[] pNams, String[] pprise) {

         pIdz=pIds;
         pNamz=pNams;

         context=ctx;
         pPrizs=pprise;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                         getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

     }

        @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pIdz==null){
                Toast.makeText(context, "There is issue with net connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Intent i=new Intent(context,WelcomeActivity.class);
                //context.startActivity(i);
                return count ;
            }else{
                return pIdz.length;
            }

        }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;

    }

    public class holder{
         TextView pid;
         TextView pname;
         TextView pprise;
         Button delete;
         ListView lv;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final holder hldr=new holder();
        View rowView = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;



          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_order_item_list, null);
          hldr.pid=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
          hldr.pname=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
          hldr.pprise=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
          hldr.delete=(Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete);       
          hldr.pid.setText(pIdz[position]);
          hldr.pname.setText(pNamz[position]);
          hldr.pprise.setText(pPrizs[position]);
          //
          //  Picasso.with(context).load(imgs[position]).into(hldr.img);
          hldr.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // rowView.remove(position); //removing from your List
                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int pid=Integer.parseInt(hldr.pid.getText().toString());

                obj.delProduct(pid);


              }
        });
           rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//               cartAdapter.this.pIdz.remove[position];

            //  Toast.makeText(context, "hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
         return rowView;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**Shopping Cart Helper file**

```
public class ShopingCartHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cart.db";
   public static final String PRODUCT_TABLE_NAME = "prodcut";
   public static final String p_id = "id";
   public static final int VERSION =1;

  SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
  SQLiteDatabase db;
  // Context context;
   public ShopingCartHelper(Context context)
   {
      super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);

   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      this.getWritableDatabase();
      db.execSQL(
      "create table prodcut " +
      "(id integer primary key, user_id text,product_name text,price text)"
      );
   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prodcut");
      onCreate(db);
   }

   public boolean insertProduct  (String user_id, String product_name, String price)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put("user_id", user_id);
      contentValues.put("product_name", product_name);
      contentValues.put("price", price);    
      db.insert("prodcut", null, contentValues);
      return true;
   }
   public void delProduct(int pid)
   {
     SQLiteDatabase database =this.getReadableDatabase();
     db.rawQuery( "delete * from prodcut where id="+pid+"", null );
   }


   public Cursor getData(String user_id){
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from prodcut where user_id="+user_id+"", null );
      return res;
   }

   public int numberOfRows(){
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, PRODUCT_TABLE_NAME);
      return numRows;
   }


}
```

**Error**

```
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at student.briyani.cartAdapter$1.onClick(cartAdapter.java:114)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-27 10:28:48.608: E/AndroidRuntime(925):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line 114 in your cartAdapter file? check what is NULL in both your click listeners.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Looks like at least `obj` is null.

Comment: if i pass context or this then generate exaption on SQLiteDatabase database =this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: All that code for a freaking NPE? Don't know why we bother with exceptions when people ignore them. Lets just go back to to good old days where the only error message was "bus error. core dumped".

Comment: Brother i want solution if there is possible to resolve this issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `obj = new ShoppingCartHelper(context)` in your Adapters constructor.

Comment: Should be no problem, he calls super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1), and getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase() are not Overridden and thus called from Superclass. Just checked my own SQL code, I get usable database in my OpenHelper without storing the context either.

Comment: But `this` on the methods is at least superflous, I'm not sure if it even has to be dropped altogether

Comment: Thanks Benjamin i already solved this that's the right solution